# Refer to Resources Created by Elastic Beanstalk from my Application?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-sqs, aws-cloudformation

So I'm working on an application for Elastic Beanstalk that makes use of SQS. I'm playing with using `.ebextensions` to have the queues created for me as part of deploy.

I can get the queues created just fine. But how do get Elastic Beanstalk/CloudFormation to tell my application about them?

For reference, I'm currently [trying to pass the URLs through environment variables](https://bitbucket.org/nge-aca/deckboom-demo/src/da8e3fadf71dfcc96da9d9ae8fa2792cb38b6ec9/.ebextensions/resources.config) but CloudFormation is choking on this.

Comment: Passing URLs through environment variables is the correct way to solve this. How is CloudFormation "choking" exactly?

Comment: It's because I didn't specify `TemplateName` or `SolutionStackName`, but copying them from [`AWSEBEnvironmentName`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environment-resources.html) fails with "Template error: instance of Fn::GetAtt references undefined resource AWSEBEnvironmentName". ([Here's that version](https://bitbucket.org/nge-aca/deckboom-demo/src/86a7a8e0ad/.ebextensions/resources.config))

And yes, I've tried just using `Ref` in my ElasticBeanstalk `option_settings`, but it seems that you can't use it outside of the CloudFormation templates.

Comment: I've also looked in to querying CloudFormation for this information, but I haven't found a way to find the CloudFormation stack that created a given EC2 instance.

Comment: EC2 instances do have tags assigned to them from CloudFormation identifying the stack, but querying the tags requires elevated permissions. Which I shouldn't need to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple solution is to use [something like this](https://github.com/awslabs/eb-node-express-sample/blob/master/.ebextensions/options.config):

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:customoption:
    NewSignupEmail: me@example.com
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    THEME: "flatly"
    AWS_REGION: '`{"Ref" : "AWS::Region"}`'
    STARTUP_SIGNUP_TABLE: '`{"Ref" : "StartupSignupsTable"}`'
    NEW_SIGNUP_TOPIC: '`{"Ref" : "NewSignupTopic"}`'
```